# Как получить attr img через native js?

Tags: javascript

Привет есть такой код

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item-wrapper"><img src="img1.png" alt="img1.png"></div>
  <div class="item-wrapper"><img src="img2.png" alt="img1.png"></div>
  <div class="item-wrapper"><img src="img3.png" alt="img1.png"></div>
  <div class="item-wrapper"><img src="img4.png" alt="img1.png"></div>
</div>
```

Надо что бы при клике на изображение получал атрибут src (надо именно на чистом js)

Comment: О каком атрибуте идет речь?

Comment: атрибут src , надо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Атрибуты элемента хранятся в свойстве `attributes` в виде объектов `DOMAttribute`. Само текстовое значение хранится в атрибуте `value`. Объект по которому кликнули, передается в обработчик события в переменной `this` (конечно, если только обработчик **не назначен** при помощи атрибута `onclick`)

```js
function imgClick() {
  console.log(this.attributes['src'].value);
}

var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.item-wrapper img');
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
  imgs[i].addEventListener('click', imgClick);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item-wrapper"><img src="img1.png" alt="img1.png"></div>
  <div class="item-wrapper"><img src="img2.png" alt="img1.png"></div>
  <div class="item-wrapper"><img src="img3.png" alt="img1.png"></div>
  <div class="item-wrapper"><img src="img4.png" alt="img1.png"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Если ты хочешь получить ссылку на картинку, то надо брать не атрибут, а свойство:

```js
var img = document.querySelector("img")
console.log(img.src)
console.log(img.getAttribute('src'))
```

```html
<img src="abc/picture.png">
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
  img[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(this.src);
  })
}
```

```css
img {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.item-wrapper {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item-wrapper"><img src="https://i1.wallbox.ru/wallpapers/main/201328/053a2cd3b325001.jpg" alt="img1.png"></div>
  <div class="item-wrapper"><img src="https://i1.wallbox.ru/wallpapers/main/201328/053a2cd3b325001.jpg" alt="img1.png"></div>
  <div class="item-wrapper"><img src="https://i1.wallbox.ru/wallpapers/main/201328/053a2cd3b325001.jpg" alt="img1.png"></div>
  <div class="item-wrapper"><img src="https://i1.wallbox.ru/wallpapers/main/201328/053a2cd3b325001.jpg" alt="img1.png"></div>
</div>
```